# Run a function using Octave from terminal

Tags: terminal, octave

I want to run a function - let's say test - inside my test.m file. I want to run this function using Octave from terminal. So, it should be something like:

```
$>/Users/me/octave/bin/octave test(param1,param2)?
```

How can I accomplish this? I can do that in Matlab. But I didn't find a way in Octave.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `octave --eval CODE`

Answer (score 2):

Octave's docs on this can be found [here](http://wiki.octave.org/FAQ#How_do_I_execute_an_Octave_script.3F). To run a function with input args:

1. In Terminal `cd` to your working directory.
2. Type `octave` to open an interactive session.
3. `ls` to check that your function's file is in your working dir, `cd` to the dir if not.
4. Type the function's name immediately followed by the input args in brackets in the correct order, Eg: `>foo(100)`. Your function will then run, spitting out whatever you print as well as all the results for lines of code not ending with `;`.